# ssh inside ssh with multiples commands

Tags: linux, ssh, tty

When I try more than one command to remotely execute commands through ssh inside other ssh, I get weird result.

From man ssh:

> ***-t***
>
> Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute
>   arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very
>   useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options
>   force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

If I do

```
ssh -t root@host1 ssh root@host2 "cat /etc/hostname && cat /etc/hostname"
```

or

```
ssh -t root@host1 ssh -t root@host2 "cat /etc/hostname && cat /etc/hostname"
```

in both cases I get

```
host1
Connection to host1 closed.
host2
Connection to host2 closed.
```

I want this result:

```
host1
host1
Connection to host1 closed.
Connection to host2 closed.
```

I want to run all commands in same server using ssh inside ssh.

If I use only one ssh, it works:

```
ssh -t root@host1 "cat /etc/hostname && cat /etc/hostname"
host1
host1
Connection to host1 closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I get it work, but I can not explain what is happening.

```
ssh -t root@host1 "ssh -t root@host2 \"cat /etc/hostname ; cat /etc/hostname\""
host1
host1
Connection to host1 closed.
Connection to host2 closed.
```

Comment: Can someone explain why only one pair of quotes not work?

Comment: With only one pair of quotes, the string `ssh -t root@host2 cat /etc/hostname && cat /etc/hostname` is passed to host 1.  (ie, the quotes have been removed by the shell).  You need the embedded quotes to send the compound command to host2.

Answer (score 0):

## Try:

That's not how -t works.

For your option try:

```
 ssh root@host1 .....; ssh root@host2 ....
```

Otherwise, use PSSH that will do the uptime command on both servers at same time:

```
pssh -h hostfile -i uptime
```

Comment: I need do SSH inside SSH, because I can not get access to host1 directly. I need do that behind host2.